# How to design a contactless mechanical shaker

Tags: oscillator, inductor, frequency, electromagnetism, high-current

I am trying to design a circuit to make an inductor oscillate with high-current (around 50A) at a low frequency. The inductor will act as a high-powered electromagnet.

Most designs I've worked/messed with for oscillators were used for higher frequencies, in MHz or KHz, like the Hartley or Colpitts oscillators. But I only want the inductor to resonate at 80Hz.

Edit: To be more specific, what would be the "best" (simplest, cheapest, more efficient, any combination of thereof) way to drive an inductor (1-10mH, this is the kind of coil I work out to obtain the electromagnetic forces required for my application) with a 80 Hz periodic signal (doesn't have to be sine, square would be better) and high current.

---

Mechanical shakers are what we have used in the past for this. However, here I need to shake an object inside a closed vessel without moving the vessel itself, only the "shaker" therein, which would be a permanent magnet. The vessel has to be non-moving so that it can be connected to rigid fittings, so fluids can be pumped in and out of it. And the fluid system can have no penetration to the outside, because no contamination must occur (biomedical application). Thus, the force must be applied at a distance with no direct contact, which is why I am looking at electromagnetism.

Comment: How big is your inductor? If you want an electromagnet, wouldn't it be easier to weigh the current versus the number of turns? Perhaps a lower current, but higher number of turns would work better, and allow you to use a smaller capacitance too.

Comment: Serious question: Have you considered using a generator instead?

Comment: What are your requirements in frequency accuracy and stability and amplitude fidelity? Are we talking about percents of tolerance, or parts per billion?

Comment: "High-powered electromagnet" implies that you want to extract energy from the inductor's magnetic field. Doing so will both change its inductance and make it extremely "lossy" -- not good if you're trying to also use it as  frequency-control element in an oscillator. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: @JorenVaes Adding more turns to the electromagnet has practical size limits if I use too low a current.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The device needs to be powered by a battery, it's not for a benchtop apparatus. Are there ways to easily get generator-like capabilities from a DC current?
Also our requirements are definitely in the percent, maintaining around 1-10% frequency accuracy would be sufficient.

Comment: @DaveTweed In short, I want to oscillate a permanent magnet at a frequency of 80 Hz with quite large forces (100's of Gs).

Comment: Mechanical vibrator is more efficient, although I have used 10kW magnetic coil exciters for 200 kG like this but not battery operated. Creating the oscillator is the easy part

Comment: 1/2 cycle @ 80Hz = 6ms @ LdI/dt= 10mH 50A /6ms = 83V ignoring losses  and 12.5 Joules and loss, saturation issues unless huge ~ 2Hp linear motor. It's possible if you have one.

Comment: what is your mechanical resonance expected?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 If I understand your question properly, there would be no resonance in the purely mechanical system, as the permanent magnet is not coupled to a spring-like component. It is simply sitting in a closed, non-magnetic, fluid-filled vessel.

Comment: OK you want a  80Hz 50Amp static coil to move some unknown magnet mass in a viscous fluid to oscillate with 100g force to pump the fluid thru pressure valves at 80 Hz.  Hmmm.  Why not use a ROLLER PUMP https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Peristaltic_pump.gif/220px-Peristaltic_pump.gif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95354/discussion-between-xylord-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Comment: @Xylord Powered by batteries and 50 A? You're aiming for car batteries... and I'd assume you'll need around 100V at least to get this amount of current through a realistic coil, so this is definitive Tesla battery territory.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed, this is a portable device, but not hand-held. This is part of the reason I was thinking of using an LC-tank type oscillator; I thought that it would be more efficient to have the current bouncing between the inductor and the capacitor at resonant freq and to trickle in power as needed using a transistor/MOSFET. But this thread has uncovered some difficulties there might be with this as well, so I think I am going to drive this using a generated function signal and a power amplifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high-powered electromagnet excited with some  sinusoidal signal?

Sounds like a PA speaker / subwoofer to me!

So, instead of building a high-powered oscillator, I'd simply use a soundcard, or a low-powered one, and feed it to a cheap power amplifier for speakers.

You'll mostly find amplifiers for 4Ω impedance loads, so to achieve 50A, you'd need P=I²/R=2500 A²/4Ω = 625 W of speaker power. (Often, stereo amps come with the ability to drive twice as much output power with the outputs bridged to just one speaker, or in your case, electromagnet.)

You can buy stage-grade PAs for that at reputable sources (Thomann etc), or you could build your own class-D amp (considering you really don't need to switch overly fast to drive something at 80 Hz).

You could of course also just build/get a class-AB amplifier, and add negative, phase-delaying feedback just so that you get your 80 Hz oscillation. That's cool, because it's then an oscillator on its own, but seriously, feeding in an external 80 Hz reference is both easier and more stable, precise and reliable.

Comment: Marcus, thanks for the post.

So, I have little experience with audio systems so bear with me, but I think I understand what you mean, in theory. I'd have a soundcard which acts as a function generator and sends a sinusoidal signal to the power amplifier. The PA takes in the signal and DC power, and outputs the signal but can supply it at a higher current. Plugs into the coil and bob's your uncle.

If all that is right, I mostly have a practical question left: what kind of soundcard? Would the one I install in my desktop computer work for this, or do you mean another kind of device?

Comment: You could use pretty much any microcontroller (e.g. Arduino) to generate a low frequency sine from its PWM analog output.

Comment: @Xylord *any* soundcard would be suitable. The one built into your desktop PC. The one in your smartphone. the one in your laptop. A USB one.